# Bitwise Multiply

Tags: binary, multiplication

just a quick question , your code does add up bits to numbers which are higher than 2 which is binary's limit ,for instance suppose n1 = 1111 and n2 is the same , then your code will show the result of 1234321 , though its not a valid binary number , How should we make the result be in binary ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you can do the following to get output in binary

```
int i1 = 1111;
int i2 = 1111;
int result = i1 * 12;
System.out.println("result in binary " + Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is the same as with decimal numbers, like you learned in school. You carry the overflow. But really, that has nothing to do with multiplication. That's just addition. For instance, 1111 x 1111 = 1111 + 11110 + 111100 + 1111000.

Answer (score 0):

You are msisunderstanding binary math. 1111 is not a binary, anyway not the 1111 which can be multipled by 1111 and results 1234321.

a binary 1111 would be 15 in Decimal. try using the windoes Calc to change between Dec. and Bin.

```
[1111 (Dec) = 10001010111 (Bin)
1111 (Bin) = 15 (Dec)
1234321 (Dec) = 100101101010110010001 (Bin)
1234321 (bin) is invlid][1]
```

Anyway you will need to go through the binary Math in order to understand how this work.

Try [this link](http://www.binarymath.info/multiplication-division.php) and see how [multiplication](http://www.binarymath.info/multiplication-division.php) works

Comment: yes thanks for this , but the question was not about this , I wrote a code to multiply binary numbers , here is the code

Comment: public static void bitwiseMultiply(int n1, int n2) {
  
    int a = n1, b = n2, result=0;
    
         while (b != 0) 
         {
             if ((b & 1) != 0)
             {  
             result += a;  
             }
             a <<= 1;             
             b >>= 1;             
         }
         System.out.println(result);
     }

Comment: The point is that the code shows that number (1234321) in case of multiplying 1111 and 1111 !! that was what I asked for,for a way of making the code to work correctly , thanks for the regard.